# Install ros groovy problem(unmet dependencies)

Tags: ros, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install ros groovy.My OS is ubuntu11.10 and 64bits.

refer website:
[http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu](http://link)

I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full
```

Appear the message: [http://notepad.cc/hovami23](http://message)

How to solve it?
thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62672/install-ros-groovy-problem(unmet-dependencies)/) by [li-an](https://answers.ros.org/users/2411/li-an/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This usually happens when there's a dependency missing somewhere. You probably don't have all of the Ubuntu sources enabled; make sure universe, multiverse and restricted are enabled.

Try to install each of the dependencies in the error message individually and see if you can track down a particular package that's missing.

I ran a dependency check on the ROS oneiric 64-bit repository, and it looks like the repository is consistent and up to date.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0